# Extract part of href link using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to python requests and beautiful soup, I was trying to create a script to automatically login and logout, but I need the "_wpnonce" value to send a valid post request. I am wondering if there is a way to extract the "_wpnonce" value from this link using beautiful soup, any help is appreciated.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=fc789123fe&redirect_to=%2Fuser%2Flogout">Sign Out</a>
```

The extracted value would be "fc789123fe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to parse the URL to components (the correct official way):

For example:

```
txt = '''<a href="https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=fc789123fe&redirect_to=%2Fuser%2Flogout">Sign Out</a>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

href = soup.select_one('a')['href']
parameters = parse_qs(urlparse(href).query)

print( parameters['_wpnonce'][0] )
```

Prints:

```
fc789123fe
```

---

To "cheat" a little bit, you can use `re` module:

```
print( re.search(r'_wpnonce=([a-f0-9]+)', soup.select_one('a')['href']).group(1) )
```

---

EDIT: To find tag `<a>` with text `Sign Out` you can do:

```
href = soup.find('a', text='Sign Out')['href']
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, is there a way you can find the element with the text "Sign Out"?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
tag = r'<a href="https://www.example.com/wp-login.phpaction=logout&amp;_wpnonce=fc789123fe&redirect_to=%2Fuser%2Flogout">Sign Out</a>'
tag = tag.split("_wpnonce=")[1]
tag = tag.split("&")[0]
print(tag)
```

output

```
fc789123fe
```